# If the mediator changes the relationship between the IV and DV is it still mediation?

Tags: regression, interaction, mediation

I found a very old question here - [Mediator reverses direction of causal variable. How to interpret?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/mediator-reverses-direction-of-causal-variable-how-to-interpret), but it isn't answered. I am having almost the same issue as @jsd. I've run mediation following Baron and Kenny and confirmed it with the Sobel test.  Here's what I get when I run the regressions (all variables are continuous):

- X significantly negatively predicts Y
- X significantly negatively predicts M
- M significantly positively predicts Y
- X + M significantly positively predict Y
- In the last model with both X and M, M no longer significantly predicts Y.

I checked moderation since the relationship reversed. There is no moderation. X and M do not significantly interact.

This post ([Mediation (b path sign changes from the correlation)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302280/mediation-b-path-sign-changes-from-the-correlation)) suggests it is mediation, but that it is suppression. I looked at suppression, but if I'm understanding it right, X and M are not supposed to have a relationship in suppression. So, do I have mediation? Or suppression? Or something else?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out. I have inconsistent mediation - Equivalence of the mediation, confounding and suppression effect MacKinnon et al., 2000 found here: http://europepmc.org/article/PMC/2819361